# How to force R to read in numerical order?

Tags: r

I have several files in one folder and I want to rename them,I noticed that R reads in alphbatical order, so I used the command `mixedsort` and it worked but when I checked the results I found that the files were read in a different order not numerically. The name of the first file is `Daily_NPP1.bin`  up to `Daily_NPP365.bin`

```
         a<- list.files("C:\\New folder (6)", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
         k<- mixedsort(a)#### load package feild
          b <- sprintf("C:carbonflux\\Daily_Rh%d.bin", seq(k))
          file.rename(a, b)
```

How do I force R to read in numerical order?

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the whole example runs fine on my computer. What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If renaming is all you want to do you could just do the following, regardless of sorting.

```
b <- sub("^.*?([0-9]+)\\.bin$", "C:\\\\carbonflux\\\\Daily_Rh\\1.bin", a)
file.rename(a, b)
```

The first argument to `sub` extracts the numbers at the end of the file names, and the second pastes it into the new file name template (at the position of `\\1`). All the `\\\\` are needed to escape the backslashes properly.

Comment: in fact I want to rename with regard to the sorting(which is very important).is your code still applicable?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. What my code does though is rename all files named `C:\New folder (6)\Daily_NPP#.bin` to `C:\carbonflux\Daily_Rh#.bin` where `#` is the same number both before and after the rename, e.g. `Daily_NPP123.bin` becomes `Daily_Rh123.bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to order the vector without renaming the files:

```
# Replication of data:
a <- sort(paste0("Daily_NPP",1:365,".bin"))

# Extract numbers and order:
a <- a[order(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","",a)))]
```

Comment: This was my initial reply too before realizing that `mixedsort` already takes care of this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. in fact I really want to rename them in respect the the order.